# Google Play Store "Error retrieving information from server [DF-AA-09]" on purchase

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

We started seeing this error from the play store when clicking on purchase - [image: Error from Play store]
We could not find a way to reproduce this error but users started seeing them recently. I could not find it on the list of known errors.

There are similar error codes like 'DF-DFERH-01' or 'DF-SA-01' which are solved by clearing the play services cache data or by removing the store account and adding it back. These methods did not solve the issue in the case of 'DF-AA-09' error.

We started seeing this error starting June 8th on the new version of google play store (11.0.55 or 11.0.56).

Anyone know what 'DF-AA-09' error means and how to reproduce and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [General Fix for Google Play Services Error Message](http://errorcodespro.com/fix-google-play-services-error-message/).

- Empty Cache
- Reset the App Preference
- Add your Google Account Once Again
- Reinstall Google Play Services
- Clear the Cache under Google Framework Services

If none of this works, you should consider [filing a report](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025).

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that I am unable to reproduce the problem. I have asked users that saw this error code to try these out (most of them) but it did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I asked about it in [google play forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/H-fdx0H-x88;context-place=forum/play) and this is the answer I got -

> Your app users might encounter such errors when there is an issue with the purchase flow or the payment methods they are using. Forcing the Play Store app to stop and clearing the cache/data of Play Store app should help in such instances.
>
> However, if their payment is declined, can't be processed, or is listed as "not eligible," trying the troubleshooting steps from the following help center article could help them [fix payment issues on their accounts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1267137?hl=en&vid=0-123728996877-1486212694864).